# Multithread App, missing operations on Images in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I've got problem with my multiThread App.
When I call the drive () method from the "Vehicles" class, I would like the objects (pictures) to move to the left. This mechanism works, but unfortunately I have a problem. Sometimes, when I run the application, it happens that one of the objects stops moving. Sometimes it is a few objects. Usually, after a fraction of a second, the images move to the left again. This behavior is not repeatable and unfortunately, it is not uncommon for small vehicles to break down and stand at the moment. Maybe one of you has an idea how to solve this problem so that the vehicles move smoothly all the time? If I put a code (System.out.println) in the marked place and I want to display the text to the console, then this mechanism works without any problems, only when the image is moved it breaks.

First class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class Main extends Application {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
StackPane root = new StackPane();
Time time;
Vehicles vehicles;
SmallVehicle1 smallVehicle1;
Text t1 = new Text();
Text t2 = new Text();
Image excavatorImage = new Image("resources/excavator.png");
//    Image smallVehicleImage = new Image("resources/small.png");
Image largeVehicleImage = new Image("resources/large.png");
ImageView imageOfExcavator1 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator2 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator3 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator4 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfExcavator5 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle1 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle2 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle3 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle4 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle5 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle6 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle7 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle8 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle9 = new ImageView(new Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfSmallVehicle10 = new ImageView(new 
Image("resources/small.png"));
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle1 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle2 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle3 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle4 = new ImageView();
ImageView imageOfLargeVehicle5 = new ImageView();


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00FF00");
    primaryStage.setTitle("My App");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
    lock.lock();
    checkTime();
    lock.unlock();
    createExcavators();
    createSmallVehicle();
    moveVehicles();

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void moveVehicles(){
    vehicles = new Vehicles(this);
    vehicles.start();
}

public void checkTime() {
    time = new Time(this);
    time.start();
    root.getChildren().add(t1);
    root.getChildren().add(t2);
}

public void updateTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    String time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    t1.setTranslateX(-450);
    t1.setTranslateY(-380);
    Platform.runLater(() -> t1.setText(time));
}

public void takeBreak() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> t2.setText("Now we have got break!"));
}

public void stopBreak() {
    takeBreak();
    t2.setTranslateY(-1000);
    t2.setTranslateX(-1000);
}

public void startBreak() {
    takeBreak();
    t2.setTranslateY(0);
    t2.setTranslateX(0);
}

public void createExcavators() {
    imageOfExcavator1.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator2.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator3.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator4.setImage(excavatorImage);
    imageOfExcavator5.setImage(excavatorImage);
    root.getChildren().addAll(imageOfExcavator1, imageOfExcavator2, imageOfExcavator3, imageOfExcavator4, imageOfExcavator5);
}

public void moveExcavator1(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator1.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator1.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator2(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator2.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator2.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator3(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator3.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator3.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator4(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator4.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator4.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveExcavator5(double x, double y) {
    imageOfExcavator5.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfExcavator5.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void createSmallVehicle() {
    root.getChildren().addAll(imageOfSmallVehicle1, imageOfSmallVehicle2, imageOfSmallVehicle3, imageOfSmallVehicle4, imageOfSmallVehicle5, imageOfSmallVehicle6, imageOfSmallVehicle7, imageOfSmallVehicle8, imageOfSmallVehicle9, imageOfSmallVehicle10);

}

public void moveSmallVehicle1(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle1.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle1.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle2(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle2.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle2.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle3(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle3.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle3.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle4(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle4.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle4.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle5(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle5.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle5.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle6(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle6.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle6.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle7(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle7.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle7.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle8(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle8.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle8.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle9(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle9.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle9.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveSmallVehicle10(double x, double y) {
    imageOfSmallVehicle10.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfSmallVehicle10.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void createLargeVehicle() {
    imageOfLargeVehicle1.setImage(largeVehicleImage);
    imageOfLargeVehicle2.setImage(largeVehicleImage);
    imageOfLargeVehicle3.setImage(largeVehicleImage);
    imageOfLargeVehicle4.setImage(largeVehicleImage);
    imageOfLargeVehicle5.setImage(largeVehicleImage);
    root.getChildren().addAll(imageOfLargeVehicle1, imageOfLargeVehicle2, imageOfLargeVehicle3, imageOfLargeVehicle4, imageOfLargeVehicle5);
}

public void moveLargeVehicle1(double x, double y) {
    imageOfLargeVehicle1.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfLargeVehicle1.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveLargeVehicle2(double x, double y) {
    imageOfLargeVehicle2.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfLargeVehicle2.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveLargeVehicle3(double x, double y) {
    imageOfLargeVehicle3.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfLargeVehicle3.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveLargeVehicle4(double x, double y) {
    imageOfLargeVehicle4.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfLargeVehicle4.setTranslateY(y);
}

public void moveLargeVehicle5(double x, double y) {
    imageOfLargeVehicle5.setTranslateX(x);
    imageOfLargeVehicle5.setTranslateY(y);
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Time extends Thread {

public int hour = 0;
public int minute = 0;
public int second = 0;
Main main;
Excavators excavators = new Excavators(main);


Time(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public void run() {
    for (; ; ) {
        try {
            second = second + 2;
            if (second == 60) {
                second = 0;
                minute++;
            }
            if (minute == 60) {
                minute = 0;
                hour++;
            }
            if (hour == 24) {
                hour = 0;
            }
            if (hour == 0 && minute == 5 && second == 0) {
            }
            setTime(hour, minute, second);
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}


public void setTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    Excavators excavators = new Excavators(main);
    excavators.start(h, m, s);
    System.out.println(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    main.updateTime(h, m, s);

}
}
```

Third class:

```
public class Excavators extends Thread {
Main main;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

Excavators(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}


public void start(int h, int m, int s){
    getTime(h, m, s);
}

public void setCoordinates1(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator1(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates2(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator2(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates3(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator3(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates4(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator4(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates5(double x, double y) {
    main.moveExcavator5(x, y);
}

public void setCoordinates() {
    setCoordinates1(-400, y);
    setCoordinates2(-200, y);
    setCoordinates3(0, y);
    setCoordinates4(200, y);
    setCoordinates5(400, y);
}

public void moveDown() {
    y = 0;
    setCoordinates();
    main.stopBreak();
}

public void moveUp() {
    y = -200;
    setCoordinates();
    main.startBreak();
}

public void stay() {
    y = 0;
    setCoordinates();
    main.stopBreak();
}

public void getTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    if (h == 0 && m >= 0 && m < 5) {
        moveDown();
    } else if (h == 0 && m >= 5 && m < 15) {
        moveUp();
    } else if (h == 0 && m >= 15 && m < 30) {
        moveDown();
    } else if(h == 0 && m >= 30 && m < 45){
        moveUp();
    }else if(h == 0 && m >= 45 && m < 60){
        moveDown();
    }else if(h == 1 && m >= 0 && m < 15){
        moveUp();
    }else{
        stay();
    }
}
}
```

Fourth class::

```
public class Vehicles extends Thread{
Main main;
double x = 100;
double y = 120;
SmallVehicle1 smallVehicle1;

Vehicles(Main main){
    this.main = main;

}



public synchronized void run(){
    for (; ; ) {
        try{
            x = x - 5;
            drive(x, y);
            Thread.sleep(40);
        }catch (InterruptedException ex){
        }
    }
}



public void reservation(){

}

public void startLoading(){

}

public void drive(double x, double y){

    /*
    HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    Objects are moving but sometimes they are stopped.
     */
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle1.setTranslateX(x);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle2.setTranslateX(x + 200);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle3.setTranslateX(x + 400);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle4.setTranslateX(x + 600);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle5.setTranslateX(x + 800);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle6.setTranslateX(x + 1000);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle7.setTranslateX(x + 1200);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle8.setTranslateX(x + 1400);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle9.setTranslateX(x + 1600);
        main.imageOfSmallVehicle10.setTranslateX(x + 1800);
}





public void checkReservation(){

}

public void stopLoading(){

}

public void smallVehicle(){

}

public void largeVehicle(){

}


}
```

Comment: Please provide a short, self sontained, correct example. This is to much irrelevant code. Most people aren't willing to read this. Try to isolate the code which describes your problem. 
I suggest to read: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Off-topic, but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: Your code is hardly readable and you duplicate a lot of code. The `drive` method is not called in the JavaFX thread application.

Comment: In some places you use `Platform.runLater` correctly and in other places you update properties of nodes (like `translateX`) without doing so. Also it would be beneficial to use a single thread for the time and trigger all updates from this thread. (Or a `Timeline` to remove the need of `Platform.runLater`.)

Comment: I will try to change my code to not repeat myself. Thank you for suggestions.@fabian Thank you very much for help, with using `Platform.runLater` the problem is gone.